# Are there tenebrescent minerals like KCl, but ideally resettable with UV/IR?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, photochemistry, crystallography, minerals

Is there a ‘simple’ mineral that is tenebrescent (getting reversibly darker on irradiation), but is resettable with UV or IR?

Hackmanite, spodumene and tugtupite ([Wikipedia examples for tenebrescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photochromism#Tenebrescence)) are only resettable by heating. $\ce{KCl}$ undergoes its color change on being bombarded with electrons in the $\pu{9 kV}$ range (that’s fine), but is also only resettable by heat.

I am looking for a (ideally ‘simple’, aka not sodalite $\ce{Na8(Al6Si6O24)Cl2}$, though I admit to not having a clear cutoff between that and sylvite $\ce{KCl})$ mineral that undergoes a color change in the visible spectrum on any kind of radiation, but is resettable by radiation in $\pu{300 nm}$ to $\pu{2500 nm}$ range.

Is there such a thing?
Is there a list?
Is there a way to predict this?